# Downloading file with curl after authenticating

Tags: shell, curl, web-scraping

### Objectives

1. I am trying to use cURL to authenticate my user credentials to a site, creating a cookie jar to store my cookie for the session.
2. With that cookie am an then trying to do the second stage of authentication which is selecting an account from a drop downlist
3. Once I have authenticated I am aiming to download a file
   based on the extended url present in the below examples - which requires me to present the most recent cookie that gets created, as new ones are created for each authenticate.

---

### Working Manual Code

```
curl -s -S -O -J -L 'https://url/report/ajax-by-tag2?platform_id\[\]=7&id1=All&id2=&id3=&id4=All&id5=&id11=&id12=&id13=&date=2019-11-17&date_start=&date_end=&website=&zfTablePage=1&zfTableColumn=&zfTableOrder=desc&zfTableQuickSearch=&zfTableItemPerPage=100&zfTableDataTablesMaxRows=31&zfDetails=false&by_viewability=imps_givt&device_id\[\]=all&tag_type_id\[\]=all&support_id\[\]=all&zfTableItemPerPage=10000&zfTableExport=xlsx' -H 'Cookie: PHPSESSID=6m1d8327ucft8052f2gjv6nfdsg6'
```

I collect the above from the network panel when I download the file manually. With the above curl I can then download the file from shell. This works by having the cookie hard stated at the end of the input.

---

### Erroring Script

```
    #!bash/sh

    -eu

curl -u usr:pwd -c ./cookiejar 'https://url/auth'
curl 'https://url/auth/adminaccounts' -d account=729&Submit=Submit
curl -s -S -O -J -L -b ./cookiejar 'https://url/report/ajax-by-tag2?platform_id\[\]=7&id1=All&id2=&id3=&id4=All&id5=&id11=&id12=&id13=&date=2019-11-17&date_start=&date_end=&website=&zfTablePage=1&zfTableColumn=&zfTableOrder=desc&zfTableQuickSearch=&zfTableItemPerPage=100&zfTableDataTablesMaxRows=31&zfDetails=false&by_viewability=imps_givt&device_id\[\]=all&tag_type_id\[\]=all&support_id\[\]=all&zfTableItemPerPage=10000&zfTableExport=xlsx'
```

---

### Issues

- When I run the "Manual code" I am able to have a file download to my current directory provided my "cookie" is a recent session that I hardcode at the end of the URL after "-H".
- When I run the "Erroring Script" it seems to run ok with the authentication, selecting the account and getting to the final line for the download part. However when it comes to running the download url it spits out the following error `curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 11895)`

Having reviewed online forums it seems to point to lack of disk space which shouldn't be the case here as it's a small excel file.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try supplying `-c ./cookiejar` to the second command in "Erroring Script" section. You are switching accounts without supplying any cookies, that probably won't work.

Comment: Do you have a write permission for the location where you're trying to download the file to?

Comment: @eyevan I've tried applying it to the front of the second command but it still returns the same error. I also tried adding -b to it but I realise that doesn't make sense now given I get a new cookie between the "log in" and the "account selection" .

Comment: It looks like [this is the error](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/d1476aa11e26019bc47cb8a3c7cd3445ac051283/lib/sendf.c#L614) you are getting -- seems like the server is dropping the connection; my guess it's not related to local file permissions and such. My advice would be to examine the cookie jar at each stage and make sure you have the right cookie (e.g., run steps 1 and 2; extract the `PHPSESSID` from the jar; use this value in `-H 'Cookie: ...'` header as in the working example)

Comment: @DawidFerenczyRogožan I can confirm I have write permissions for the download location. For now I am just trying to get it to download to my current working directory, which is "my documents" folder.

Comment: In the second command `curl 'https://url/auth/adminaccounts ...`, you have to use quotes around `account=729&Submit=Submit`

Comment: Consider running all curl with `-v` (or even with trace) - this will give you lot of information about progress, and problems

Comment: @dash-o -v helped solve the issue. It was an incorrect path url for the auth page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

rm -f cookiejar ##deletes cookiejar file at the start, so no cookies are saved

curl -o /dev/null -s -S -L -f -c cookiejar 'https://url/auth/authenticate' -d name=usr-d passwd='pwd' ##supplies user creds

curl -o /dev/null -s -S -L -f -b cookiejar -c cookiejar 'https://url/auth/adminaccounts' -d account=23225 ##selects account

curl -s -S -L -O -J -f -b cookiejar -c cookiejar 'https://url/report/ajax-by-tag2?platform_id\[\]=7&id1=All&id2=&id3=&id4=All&id5=&id11=&id12=&id13=&date=2019-11-17&d$' ##downloads file
```